# WEB9031 - cannot store entity with sequence generated id

Tags: jpa, glassfish, ejb

I am using glassfish, postgres and openjpa.

I only have one bean and first want to create a new intance and store it in DB. I created a new User-Object, filled it (except the id) and got - trying to persist - following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [org.apache.openjpa.util.LongId], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1401)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
at org.myPlace.server.user.UserPDO.pcNewObjectIdInstance(UserPDO.java)
at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCRegistry.newObjectId(PCRegistry.java:142)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processRegisteredClass(MetaDataRepository.java:1694)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processRegisteredClasses(MetaDataRepository.java:1644)
... 128 more

 WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for
 servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource   
 [org.apache.openjpa.util.LongId], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1401)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
at org.myPlace.server.user.UserPDO.pcNewObjectIdInstance(UserPDO.java)
at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCRegistry.newObjectId(PCRegistry.java:142)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processRegisteredClass(MetaDataRepository.java:1694)
```

My bean looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_User")
public class UserPDO implements Serializable {

private long id;
private String username;
private String password;

public UserPDO() {}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="user_seq_gen") 
@SequenceGenerator(name="user_seq_gen", sequenceName="user_seq")
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

... }
```

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="myPlace" transaction-type="JTA">

    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>

    <class>org.myPlace.server.user.UserPDO</class>

    <properties>
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="postgres"/>

      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myPlace"/>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="myPlace"/>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="myPlace"/>

      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/> 
      <property name="openjpa.Log" value="File=/home/username/apache.log, DefaultLevel=ERROR, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>

      <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="false" />
      <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported" />
      <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="false"/>
      <property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="false"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

The table is created correctly, so is the sequence. But when I want to create a new user object via

```
public <T> T create(T t) {
    this.em.persist(t);
    this.em.flush();
    this.em.refresh(t);
    return t;
}
```

I get the exception mentioned above. I found some questions/answers here that suggest that deactiving runtime-enhancement should do the trick. But it didn't work for me. My first idea was, that it might be a Classloader-Leak. I copied postgres-driver and openjpa-jars into the glassfish/lib-folder.

Can anybody help? Thanks!